# Cannot upload package to the Windows app store. VS prints "error MSB4044"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

My app is running successfully before I try to upload it into the App store. When I try to release the App to the store Visual Studio 2015 prints this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2114,5): error MSB4044: 未给任务“GenerateAppxPackageRecipe”的必需参数“AppxManifestXml”赋值。

It says that I haven't assigned a value for the task `GenerateAppxPackageRecipe` in required parameter `AppxManifestXml`.

If I use a friend's `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage` the same error is printed, but my friend can upload the package into the App store.

You can check my code at https://github.com/lindexi/csdn-uwp

Can anyone help detecting what is going on? Any idea on advance?

Comment: Could you explain what "relevance the app store" means? What are the steps you do in Visual Studio to get there?

Comment: When I want to upload my package,I should make a package,and if I want to make a package that I should login my account and list all my app name,and then I should select one of my app name to use or creat a new name.And this is my means.And I should say,in china,login in my account and list my app will make me pay a half hour.And with the development of my app number I will use more and more time to wait the list load.

Comment: To save you time in connecting to associate your app with the store, you can follow the steps here to try and create a package for the store: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/12/15/building-an-app-for-a-3rd-party-how-to-package-their-store-app/. I'm not sure why the package is failing though... just trying to save you some money for internet.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015.3 ,I not found this question.